# Xamarin.Forms - HTML tag on Label using resx file

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Is it possible use HTML tags in resx file and use it as text of label?
I tried to use `<b>`Some text`</b>` but not working. The tags are print as text.

I need a solution cross platform (Android & iOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xamarin.Forms v4.3 and above your label can directly host HTML tags and work something like for instance

When you check the Microsoft documents you will see:

```
Label label = new Label
{
    Text = "This is <strong style=\"color:red\">HTML</strong> text.",
    TextType = TextType.Html
};
```

> In the example above, the double-quote characters in the HTML have to be escaped using the \ symbol.
>
> In XAML, HTML strings can become unreadable due to additionally escaping the < and > symbols:

```
<Label Text="This is &lt;strong style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt; text."
   TextType="Html"  />
```

> Alternatively, for greater readability, the HTML can be inlined in a CDATA section

```
<Label TextType="Html">
<![CDATA[
This is <strong style="color:red">HTML</strong> text.
]]>
</Label>
```

> In this example, the Label.Text property is set to the HTML string that's inlined in the CDATA section. This works because the Text property is the ContentProperty for the Label class.
>
> The following screenshots show a Label displaying HTML:

### **NOTE: Displaying HTML in a Label is limited to the HTML tags that are supported by the underlying platform.**

Also just tested with Resx and that works too!

Comment: It's work fine in Android but on iOS the text font appear different. Thank you